# Swap two values in a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have a table with two columns, Name and Priority. Let's assume the current data is (A,1)(B,2)(C,3)(D,4).

Now from the UI, I'm editing D. That is I'm updating D's priority to 2. Now I should update D's priority as 2 and set B's priority to 4. I'm swapping the priorities of D and B. How do I do this? My project uses Entity framework. This is how I'm currently doing,

```
public void Swap(InputObject input)
        {
            NamePriority prio = context.NamePriorities.Where(w => w.Name == input.Name.FirstOrDefault();
            NamePriority prioToSwap = context.NamePriorities.Where(w.Priority == input.Priority).FirstOrDefault();
            prioToSwap.Priority = prio.Priority;
            context.SaveChanges();
            prio.Priority = input.Priority;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Is there a simpler or cleaner way to do this like using a LINQ lambda expression or something?

Comment: you don't need save changes twice, that will not reflect the value in case you get it again from the database. What are you trying to accomplish is not a regular swap? the same as int a = 3, int b = 2, int temp= 0; temp=a;a=b;b=tmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first call to `SaveChanges` and that would be it. What you are doing is picking the two objects to modify, modifying them and saving changes. I don't see anything that might make the code simpler.

However, note that you are ignoring the possibility that one or both objects might not be found in the database.

```
public void Swap(InputObject input)
{
    NamePriority prio = 
        context.NamePriorities
            .Where(w => w.Name == input.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (prio == null) return; // This was missing

    NamePriority prioToSwap = 
        context.NamePriorities
            .Where(w.Priority == input.Priority).FirstOrDefault();

    if (prioToSwap == null) return;  // This was missing

    prioToSwap.Priority = prio.Priority;
    prio.Priority = input.Priority;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The part which makes this code a bit confusing is selecting the objects. If this is truly the domain logic you have to follow, then that's it.

You might try to simplify the selection criteria for the two objects that need to be swapped, and that is all I can recommend.

**Alternate Solution**

It crosses my mind that you might be solving the problem using wrong tools.

What is the purpose of priority in your design? From your example, it looks like you are promoting objects that have been updated last.

Why persisting priority instead of having each object be represented with name and the timestamp of the last update (which is originally the insert time)?

If this organization satisfies your domain logic, then prioritizing objects turns to sorting them descending by timestamp, rather than explicit priority and you could remove this entire `Swap` function.

Comment: Yeah, the terminology is confusing in the question. The term priority usually doesn't imply the values are mutually exclusive. Having unique values might imply a rank, but then I'd expect B=3, C=4 in the example.